# pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation< PointInT, PointOutT >::setInputCloud() makes runtime SFINAE exception

Tags: templates, eigen, feature-extraction, point-cloud-library

I am using PCL version 1.12.1 on Ubuntu 22.
The eigen3 version is 3.4.0

The full code is in written [here](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/normal_estimation_using_integral_images.html#normal-estimation-using-integral-images).

In here, `pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation< PointInT, PointOutT >` is used.

```
int main ()
{
    // load point cloud
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("./img/table_scene_mug_stereo_textured.pcd", *cloud);

    // estimate normals
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);

    pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> ne;
    ne.setNormalEstimationMethod (ne.AVERAGE_3D_GRADIENT);
    ne.setMaxDepthChangeFactor(0.02f);
    ne.setNormalSmoothingSize(10.0f);
    ne.setInputCloud(cloud); /*Here comes a problem.*/
    ne.compute(*normals); /*The debugger couldn't reach here.*/

    // visualize normals
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("PCL Viewer");
    viewer.setBackgroundColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    viewer.addPointCloudNormals<pcl::PointXYZ,pcl::Normal>(cloud, normals);

    while (!viewer.wasStopped ())
    {
        viewer.spinOnce();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It makes no compile error but makes runtime error and the program is terminated.

> normal_estimation_using_integral_images: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:133: Eigen::internal::variable_if_dynamic<T, Value>::variable_if_dynamic(T) [with T = long int; int Value = 3]: Assertion `v == T(Value)' failed.

Call stack is as the below.

> libc.so.6!__pthread_kill_implementation(int no_tid, int signo, pthread_t threadid) (pthread_kill.c:44)
> libc.so.6!__pthread_kill_internal(int signo, pthread_t threadid) (pthread_kill.c:78)
> libc.so.6!__GI___pthread_kill(pthread_t threadid, int signo) (pthread_kill.c:89)
> libc.so.6!__GI_raise(int sig) (raise.c:26)
> libc.so.6!__GI_abort() (abort.c:79)
> libc.so.6!__assert_fail_base(const char * fmt, const char * assertion, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * function) (assert.c:92)
> libc.so.6!__GI___assert_fail(const char * assertion, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * function) (assert.c:101)
> libpcl_features.so.1.12![Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code] (Unknown Source:0)
> libpcl_features.so.1.12!pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal>::initAverage3DGradientMethod() (Unknown Source:0)
> pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal>::setInputCloud(pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> * const this, const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr & cloud) (/usr/include/pcl-1.12/pcl/features/integral_image_normal.h:251)
> main() (/home/sagal/bire/pcl_tutorial/src/normal_estimation_using_integral_images.cpp:91)

I suspect the problem have came from just-in-time code generation failure of PCL library of which couldn't pass SFINAE check of Eigen library.

But I cannot know why and where the type-test is needed.

How can I resolve or bypass the error?

Comment: The failed assertion is not related to SFINAE. The assertion is triggered if an object with size at compile-time known to be 3 is getting constructed using a dynamic-size constructor, but not given the size 3 -- from the stack trace I can't tell anything more specific. If no PCL expert here can resolve this, maybe also report this as issue to PCL.

Comment: I have this exact same problem